# Promoting certain client's ads in search result

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working on an e-commerce website. We are listing jobs on our platform... we have different agencies who list their jobs on our site... let's call them Agency1, Agency2 and Agency3

Agnecy1 is paying us additional fee and we want to promote their ads to appear higher up in the search result. Is it possible to achieve this using Elasticsearch?

I have seen [boost](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html) which allows to boost a specific field, but not sure if this is useful for this scenario? I don't want to boost any specific field... I want to boost all the jobs which belong to Agency1.

### Update

I have one index called `job` which has the following fields:

- Title (string)
- Description (string)
- Job Category (string)
- MinSalary (integer)
- MaxSalary (integer)
- Location (string)
- Agency (string)
- Start Date (DateTime)
- End Date (DateTime)

And as explained earlier, if Agency = 'Agency1' I want to promote their job listing to appear higher up in the search result.

Comment: Need more context. The index mapping, sample docs etc.

Comment: @JoeSorocin: I have included the fields in the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure this is possible using `bool` query.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        // Your current query
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
              "term": { "Agency": "Agency1" }
            },
            "boost": 1.2
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

`bool` query allows specifying a query clause that `must` match. `should` clauses do not filter out documents, only boost them in case of a match.

So in this case, wrap your current query under `must` and the following query will give add a constant of `1.2` to the score of matched documents, in your case - to the ones who belong to `Agency1` agency.

Read more about [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I will try this solution tomorrow. As the e-commerce website grows there will be several Agencies which should be boosted. I believe I would have to use `TermsQuery` to boost multiple Agencies?

Comment: In the above scenario (multiple agencies) do you know if it would be better to use `TermsQuery` or logically `OR` multiple `TermQuery`s? This is actually a totally different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65714051/most-efficient-way-to-limit-search-result-to-list-of-ids) which I asked a while ago.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini You can totally use `TermsQuery` to boost multiple Agencies. Giving that you're fine that all of them would get exactly the same `boost` value. If you need to provide a different score for agencies, just add multiple queries to `should: [...]` clause with boosts you want to apply.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest approach that comes to mind would include a score addition inside of a [`function_score` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-script-score). Assuming you have a [`.keyword` mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) set on the `Agency` field, you can do:

```
POST job/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "function_score": {
            "functions": [
              {
                "script_score": {
                  "script": {
                    "source": "_score + (doc['Agency.keyword'].value == params.agency_to_promote ? params.increase_score_by : 0)",
                    "params": {
                      "agency_to_promote": "Agency 1",
                      "increase_score_by": 10
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The above script could also be [stored](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html#modules-scripting-stored-scripts) for faster execution. The factor `10` is arbitrary -- adjust it to suit your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wish the person who has downvoted this question would add a comment, to elaborate the drawback of this approach...

Comment: True -- but you can compare both approaches and upvote this one if it works better for you 

Comment: Aren't functions executed at the end of the query? I mean if we are getting a paged result, this function would only modify the first page's score... but we needed the score to determine the content of the first page... I am just guessing...

Comment: Sorry, it was me who downvoted it. While it should be working, this is a very brute-force approach. It'll cost a lot of CPU, won't scale well, will scan all filtered search results. This is really an anti-way of querying Elasticsearch efficiently.